# want to print json data individually

Tags: angularjs

on the node server i am sending data to angular as

```
res.json(data);
```

at angular i'm making http request to get the data

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/doctor/getDocData'
}).then(function(response) {

    $scope.docData=JSON.stringify(response);
    alert($scope.docData) //alert data 
    alert($scope.docData.name); //undefined
 }, function(response) {
    alert("error in loading data")
```

})
 i want to sore the received data and individually print when ever i want. what am i doing wrong.Some one please explain. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't `JSON.stringify()` the response as that is turning it back into a string, rather than parsed, structured JSON. Just target the data directly. If you are using `$http` you may need to get at `data` of the `response` object:

`$scope.docDate = response.data;`

Then you can target the properties:

`alert($scope.docData.name);`

If for some reason your JSON is coming in as a string, instead of JSON, you can use `JSON.parse(response.data)` to parse the string to JSON. This assumes it's formatted correctly.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: it worked but just a question why we are using response.data

Comment: $http returns an object with the body of the response in the `data` property. It's in the official `$http` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Please mark the answer that helped resolve your issue.

Comment: i was having this problem for about an hour so i asked for help. thanks anyway, u been a great help.

Comment: Glad to help. It threw me off at first too when first working with `$http` in Angular.